# Back Button command visible in android too

Tags: java, android, ios, codenameone

It sets the back Button in titlebar of ios

```
f.setBackCommand(new Command("News") {
}
```

Is there any way to display the back icon in android too just like in ios ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can display back icon on android, use Toolbar API for this:

```
Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
f.setToolBar(t);
Command news = new Command("News", myIcon) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
};
news.putClientProperty("uiid", "BackCommand");
f.setBackCommand(news);
t.addCommandToLeftBar(news);
t.setTitle("My Form");
```

Comment: hello @diamond i override setIcon inside command jst like actionPerformed as abov but the icon doesnt appear. What else i have to do ?

Comment: tysm. but why dont overriding setIcon method work it should have worked, isn't it?